# Include Jade/pug в webpack с vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, jade, webpack2

Вот пример использования препроцессора jade/pug без webpack и vuejs, который состоит из двух файлов второй "инклудится" в первый.
Вот основной main.jade:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title Jade
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container.col
      p You are amazing
    include content.jade
```

И вот второй content.jade:

```
.container.content
   p Content
```

Как подобное сделать в webpack с vuejs, если это возможно, то есть как один файл подсоединить к другому с помощью директивы "include"?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, думаю, это невозможно сейчас. И вот основания так думать -
 https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/472. Дело в том, что в VueJs система шаблонов - это "компоненты".

Comment: Т.е. нет возможности заинклюдить из одного file.vue (содержит <template>) в другой <template>?